# How can I remove and disable swap space?

Tags: release-freya, boot, system, swap

on boot I get a message that is really annoying saying that my drive used for swap space is not ready yet or something around those lines.

How can I disable and remove my swap space? I have 12gb of RAM so I think there should not be an issue with not having swap space.

Comment: You're better off tracking down the cause of the error rather than disabling swap all together. Is your swap partition encrypted? Have you added or removed any disks? [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289858/disk-drive-for-dev-mapper-cryptswap-1-is-not-ready) answer may be of use.. though I have included several methods to disable it anyway if you go that route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Temporary**

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

**Permanent**

First we must tell the system not to attempt to mount the swap partition on boot.

```
sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/fstab
```

Comment out (place a # before) or delete the line containing your swap partition which will be similar to this.

```
...
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=3532d79f-8215-435b-b40e-36136e0e2a41 none swap sw 0 0
...
```

Then you can delete the swap partition with your partitioner of choice. Below is an example using GParted which can be installed via `sudo apt-get install gparted`. Note that you will need to run the `swapoff` command above (or select it from the GParted menu), before you can delete the partition.

[image: GParted]